# How to submit a POST request to Apache Syncope API in node.js?

Tags: node.js, apache, http-post

Salam (means Hello) :)

In my node.js application, I am trying to add a user to Apache Syncope via its RESTful API. Apache Syncope is installed on a remote VPS and [this article](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SYNCOPE/Calling+RESTful+services+from+CLI#CallingRESTfulservicesfromCLI-Exportdatabasecontent) demonstrate this process in a PHP environment. here is what I did in my node.js application:

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(80);

function onRequest (request, response) {
    var options = {
        hostname: MY_VPS_IP,
        port: 8080,
        path: '/syncope/rest/user/create.json',
        auth: 'admin:password',
        method: 'POST'
    };
    var data = {an: 'object', of: 'new', user: 'data' };

    var req=http.request(options, function(res) {
        var body;
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            response.end(body, 'utf-8');
        });
    });
    req.end(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

The response of Apache Syncope is a 415 error (css styles omitted):

```
undefined
<html>
<head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 - Error report</title>
</head>
<body><h1>HTTP Status 415 - </h1>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
<p><b>type</b> Status report</p>

<p><b>message</b> <u></u></p>

<p><b>description</b> <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the
    requested resource for the requested method.</u></p>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
<h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42</h3></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Node uses chuncked transfer encoding, which isn't supported by Syncope here. Since you probably already run nginx, just stick that in front of Syncope.

Comment: @DamonGant I'm not familiar with nginx may you explain what do you mean by 'sticking that in front of Syncope'? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js will use chuncked transfer encoding for sending requests, which is part of HTTP 1.1. Getting around this inside Node.js is  neither desireable, fast or elegant. A common solution is to proxy the incompatible service though nginx (which will re-encode the request). Here's a very simple example configuration for reverse-proxing.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name syncope.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/;
    allow 127.0.0.1; # Allow local connections, can be any IP(+CIDR) too
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Apache Syncope is installed on Apache Tomcat, is there a way to handle this situation by reconfiguring Tomcat and without nginx?

Comment: @NasserTorabzade No idea, but you want nginx in front of your node app aswell to serve static files or to use [passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Node.js-tutorial)